# How can I click the option without input value change in antd autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, antd

In autocomplete, when you click the option, input value will change,
But I want the input value immutable when I click the option.
I have tried to change the value back in onSelect call back.
Mostly the input value will change to the option value first, then change to the given value, it work, but not that smooth, and sometimes it didn't change.
This is the code

```
<div className="search-container">
    <AutoComplete
      className="global-search"
      size="large"
      dropdownClassName="certain-category-search-dropdown"
      dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
      dropdownStyle={{ width: 300, top: 47 }}
      dataSource={options}
      onSelect={()=>{this.value = value | ''}}
      onSearch={this.inputValueChange}
      placeholder={formatMessage(messages.searchPlaceHolder)}
      optionLabelProp=""
      filterOption={false}
    >
      <Input
        suffix={(
          <Button className="search-btn" size="large" type="primary">
            <Icon type="search" />
          </Button>
        )}
      />
    </AutoComplete>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question:

> But I want the input value immutable when I click the option

I think you can use value + onSelect to make AutoComplete under control, see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components